# Get several video frames as fast as possible using iphone's camera with swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

My goal is that when user press a button, several video frames are captured as fast as possible and finally saved into photo album in iphone.

I am not familiar with swift, so I use a very crappy implementation. I define a int number with 0, and change it to the frame numbers that I want to capture when user presses the button.

```
var number:Int? = 0

@IBAction func takeFrames(sender: UIButton) {
    self.number=5;
}
```

then in the delegate I save these frames to photo album:

```
func captureOutput(captureOutput: AVCaptureOutput!, didOutputSampleBuffer sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer!, fromConnection connection: AVCaptureConnection!) {
    if(number>0) {
        let rawImage:UIImage = self.imageFromSampleBuffer(sampleBuffer)
        let img = UIImagePNGRepresentation(rawImage)
        let pngImg = UIImage.init(data: img!)
        UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(pngImg!, nil, nil, nil)
        print("PNG frame write to photo album successfully")
        number = number!-1;
    }

}
```

My question is:

1) Can I use more elegant and safe way to use button pressing to control the frames capturing?

2) Currently, I save the frame one by one, so I don't achieve the goal that capture frames as soon as possible, can I capture all frames that I need and save them into photo album once in the end?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try doing this:

```
    let imageArray: NSMutableArray?
    for _ in 0 ..< 5  {
        let rawImage:UIImage = self.imageFromSampleBuffer(sampleBuffer)
        let img = UIImagePNGRepresentation(rawImage)
        let pngImg = UIImage.init(data: img!)
        imageArray?.addObject(pngImg!)

    }
    for image in imageArray! {
        UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image as! UIImage, nil, nil, nil)
    }
    print("PNG frame write to photo album successfully")
```

Swift can sometimes be confusing in for statements. This will take '5' images.

Comment: Thanks. Following your suggestion, I use a "var imageArray = [CMSampleBuffer?]()" to get all the frames, and finally do the transformation and save work.  Any suggestion for my question 1)?

Comment: @JunFang not sure. You could try using a guard statement or a try block. That would definitely make it safe. I think you are fine though.